# SoundPool or MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I am making an android app that plays different sound files by clicking on different image buttons. The sound files will be 10 - 15 seconds max and I plan on having about 20 - 25 different sound files. I do have knowledge on implementing both SoundPool and MediaPlayer but I don't know which one to go for, more specifically which one would be more suitable and use less memory resource in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since [`SoundPool`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) stores sounds uncompressed in memory for instant playback and performing pitch changing effects you should definitely go for [`MediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) in your case. One reused `MediaPlayer` instance should be sufficient, unless you need to be able to play back multiple sounds simultaneously. In that case you can create a small pool of reusable `MediaPlayer` instances. Do not instantiate too many of them because they occupy audio track system resources which are limited to something like 30 as far as I recall.

In my last Android game I use both `SoundPool` for very short sound clips (~1 sec per clip) and a pool of 5 reusable `MediaPlayer` instances for longer ones. There is little noticeable playback latency with `MediaPlayer`.

You could also take that mixed approach. If your app has shorter sound clips that need instantaneous and repeated / simultaneous playback, you could load them into a `SoundPool`.